# How do I include multiple statements in a thin arrow function?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, modal-dialog

This works:

```
<script>
    $(modal).on("click", 'input[type="submit"]', (e) ->
        modal.modal('hide'))
</script>
```

But how do I to additionally include an `alert("Success!")` in the above, so that it both hides the modal and then displays an alert when submit is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

You need braces around to signify a new block that allows for multiple statements. Without it, the function can only execute one line. Try this:

```
$(modal).on("click", 'input[type="submit"]', (e) -> {
    modal.modal('hide');
    alert("Success!");
});
```

This uses some braces to create a function that can execute more than one line. Your previous example is similar to a shorthand if statement like so:

```
if(5 > 3) 
    console.log("Hello!");
```

It's great for short blocks of code, but you need braces if you want more than one line of code:

```
if(5 > 3) {
    console.log("Hello!");
    alert("Apples!");
}
```